# exclude method in module for use in multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, module

so i've got one pretty simple method in a model here:

```
  def log
    self.statistics.build()
    self.save
    return
  end
```

now i wanted to exclude this method into a module to use it in different models.

```
module Statistic
  def log
    self.statistics.build()
    self.save
    return
  end
end
```

i added the file to the autoload paths and included it into my model (the inclusion works fine).

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Statistic
end
```

trying to call the `.log` method results in an error:
`undefined method`new' for Statistic:Module`the raised line number is the`self.statistics.build()` line.

any ideas why this is not working?

thanks for all hints! please leave a comment if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a naming clash.

It seems you have a `has_many :statistics`, by default this will look for a class called `Statistic`.

But this is the same name as the module you have created.

I suggest renaming your module to `StatisticsExtensions` or something of that sort.

Comment: oh yes, you are right. any tipps for naming the file and the Module? `StatisticsExtensions` does not seem to work, but some random name does. how should the file be named? `statisticsExtensions` ?

Comment: the module `AbcDef` should live in a file named `abc_def.rb`, the module `Ghi::JklMno` should be a file names `jkl_mno.rb` inside a subdirectory named `ghi`, ie. `ghi/jkl_mno.rb`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing a missing method for new is because build is an alias for new in the ActiveRecord source. It's assuming statistics is an active record relation, and it's not.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d22592a05b299c21e30ec8b38890a178dca863b4/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L83